# Logic to display excel background shade using asp.net & EPPlus

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, epplus

I have an asp.net application that is exporting data to excel. I need to shade the cells in the excel file.

I would like the 1st row to have a darkgray background. The second row to have a light graybackground and the 3rd row to be regular white. Then loop (darkgray, lightgray, white etc).

Currently, using EPPlus, this is my code:

```
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 1
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1

        Dim xlRow = excelWorksheet.Row(rowIndex)
        Dim xlCell = excelWorksheet.Cells(rowIndex, colIndex)

        Dim CellFill = xlCell.Style.Fill
        Dim RowFill = xlRow.Style.Fill

        CellFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
        RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
        RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Drawing.Color.DarkGray)
```

This would be very long and complex if I was to code for every cell. How can I make this into a loop ? Ideally, I would like a range of columns (example Column A: Column E)

Comment: Put your 3 fill colors into an array, then use the **Mod** operator to calculate the array index from the rowIndex variable.

Comment: funny.. I tried that but couldn't get the logic to work. Can you whip out a psuedo code block?

Comment: Sorry - not a VB.NET person: Tim's solution below is pretty much the same thing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested but should give you the clue:

```
For row = workSheet.Dimension.Start.Row To workSheet.Dimension.End.Row
    Dim pos = row Mod 3
    Dim rowRange = workSheet.Row(row)
    Dim RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill
    RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid
    Select Case pos
        Case 0
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Drawing.Color.LightGray)
        Case 1
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Drawing.Color.DarkGray)
        Case 2
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Drawing.Color.White)
    End Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is looking for C#, as was I.

```
for (int row = worksheet.Dimension.Start.Row; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
{
    int pos = row % 3;
    ExcelRow rowRange = worksheet.Row(row);
    ExcelFill RowFill = rowRange.Style.Fill;
    RowFill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    switch (pos)
    {
        case 0:
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);
            break;
        case 1:
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.DarkGray);
            break;
        case 2:
            RowFill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            break;
    }
```